# printf() swallowing bytes in fcgi mode

Tags: c, printf, fastcgi

I am using a C program with fastcgi which calls the following function to produce an output line with comma-separated numbers:

```
void print_numbers( double* numbers, int n) {
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    printf("%s%.4lf",i>0?",":"",numbers[i]);
}
```

This works as expected when I start the program from the console - it prints a list of numbers like

```
280.3689,223.3237,271.8893,241.5658,...
```

However, when I use the program as fastcgi worker process and call it from the browser, it only prints a series of commas instead:

```
,,,,,,,,,,
```

I have seen that fcgi re`#define`s "printf" via macro and routes the call to `FCGI_printf()` instead. It seems that some output is "swallowed" in the browser / fcgi environment, whereas everything works fine from the console.

Also, when I avoid `printf()` and work with `sprintf()` instead:

```
void print_numbers( double* numbers, int n) {
  char s[20],t[500];
  *t = '\0';
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    sprintf(s,"%s%.4lf",i>0?",":"",numbers[i]);
    strcat(t,s);
    }
  printf(t);
}
```

Then again, everything works fine, also in the browser, I get my comma-separated list. But I want to be sure that I can use `printf()` with all its features in my fcgi programs!

Any ideas? Is this a known problem? (I work on Ubuntu 14.04 with `fcgi-2.4.1-SNAP-0311112127` as downloaded from http://www.fastcgi.com )

**Edited**:

The problem was easily reproduceable with a little C test program. I have placed it on gist: 
https://gist.github.com/rplantiko/18e8e859175f93454550

Comment: Since the commas ARE appearing, there doesn't seem to be a problem with the tertiary operator. Perhaps it doesn't recognize the %.4lf for some reason, either the .4 or the double

Comment: @Emisor You are right: When I change the `%.4lf` to `%.4f` in the `printf` statement, then the output will be as ecpected! But I am "strongly discouraged" by every serious C reference to use the `%f` format specifier for printing `double`values. What to do? And how to explain the behavior?